# Chat ban reason still showing "automatically suspended for posting inappropriate content" even when it's not true anymore

Tags: bug, chat, chat-ban

When a user is suspended on a main site (say, for 30 days), the chat profile will show such a banner:

> This user is suspended on the parent site and cannot chat for 29 days.

That's good.

Now if while being suspended on the parent site, the user also gets one of their chat messages flagged and deleted due to the flag, an automated 30 minutes chat ban is added and the banner changes to this:

> This user has been automatically suspended for posting inappropriate content and cannot chat for 29 days.

This is correct for the 30 minutes of the automated ban, however the banner **never gets back** to what it was before, and there's a false impression that the user posted a ton of inappropriate content.

A similar issue also occurs for manual moderator chat suspensions: the suspension reason **continues to show** as "automatically suspended for posting inappropriate content" even after the automatic ban duration, and never changes back to "suspended by a moderator".

Can the chat profile banner get updated once the latest reason expires?

Comment: I agree that the behavior is arguably not ideal, but there are no separate bans. The times *get added up.* It is thus not clear when the 30 minutes occur. To be somewhat consistent they ought to be added *at the end*. If not the user would be suspended for being suspended on the parent site *while not actually being suspended there.* In other words, it is not the case that after 30 minutes the latest reason expired. If anything it kicks in after the preexisting one is over and arguably should only be displayed then.

Comment: The best way to resolve this is to not change the banner even if the suspension is extended due to a flagged message, i e. continue to show it as a parent site suspension or a moderator suspension.