# Can you appeal accidental chat suspensions?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, chat-flags, chat-ban

I recently was accidentally suspended in the Winter Bash chat (about two weeks ago).

The reason for the suspension was that another user flagged my comment (I requested deletion as it had a spoiler for the unicorn puzzle) but didn't know about different flags, so they flagged as spam/offensive. As a result of this, I got a 30-minute chat suspension.

Luckily, a moderator noticed and un-suspended me. However, if no moderators were in the chat room, I would have been suspended for the full half an hour.

Is there a way to appeal chat suspensions which happened by accident? Or do you have to wait out the suspension time?

Relevant: After getting accidentally suspended (provided there was evidence it was an accident and moderators fixed the suspension) is it possible to get the suspension removed from your list of past suspensions?

For clarification, I'm mostly talking about 24-hour chat suspensions or longer as a result of accidents.

Comment: For a 30-minute chat suspension, due to the rather short time, I think it's better to just wait it out rather than to try and get it reversed, and that's probably what you may be told in the future. Also, when it comes to chat suspensions, as far as I'm aware, no log is maintained for those, and instead manual annotations are used to indicate prior behavior. If there is a log, there's probably no way to have entries removed from the database, and so what would most likely occur is an annotation placed on your profile that the suspension was accidental.

Comment: I mean stuff like a 24-hour chat suspension.

Comment: Also, a quick note: chat suspensions don't count toward the rule that one can't have been suspended in the past year on the network to run in a moderator election: that rule only regards site suspensions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technical question first:

> After getting accidentally suspended (provided there was evidence it was an accident and moderators fixed the suspension) is it possible to get the suspension removed from your list of past suspensions?

No; it's permanently on the list and visible to moderators on chat. However, it will also be noted that you were manually *un*suspended, and I'd recommend that the unsuspending moderator leave an annotation to explain to future mods as well. (Annotations are like private sticky notes that mods can leave on users. They're only visible to mods.)

Longer suspensions are pretty much always manually issued.
Automated suspensions are given in increments of 30 minutes; the automated suspension is increased by 30 minutes for each flag-deleted message. Therefore, it would take 48 flag-deleted messages to give you an automated 24-hour chat suspension.

Longer suspensions are manually issued by moderators and are given in numbers of hours. As with any suspension, in order to appeal it, you can reach out to [the CM team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-is-on-the-community-management-team-and-what-does-it-do) via the "contact" form.
If you believe it was an accident (i.e., someone issued a suspension from the wrong tab), you can also post on the meta site of whatever site your chat account is parented to and request a second look. In general, though, to appeal a suspension, you should reach out to SE staff.

Comment: It should be noted that due to a [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354390/377214), if a user who's under a manual chat suspension or parent site suspension gets one or more of their messages flagged and deleted, the notice will incorrectly indicate they've been automatically suspended for a long time for posting inappropriate content. So if a suspension notice indicates a 24-hour automatic suspension, it could also be a 24-hour manual suspension plus one of their messages was flag-deleted, rather than 48 of their messages being flag-deleted at once.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do to appeal a suspension:

1. Flag one of your messages for mod attention and explain the problem.
2. Go to the [contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and select *appeal suspension* and then choose a chat suspension, though a short suspension probably won't be reviewed until it's already over since only SE staff can review stuff submitted in the contact form.

But note: don't beg to be unsuspended. If a moderator says that the suspension was reasonable, don't argue.

Also, 24-hour suspensions are still not that long. It can go up to 9999 hours